# What is the ASP.NET tag <blac:?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am pretty new to ASP.NET and C# and am beginning to take over a large project from a previous developer.  I've encountered an ASP.NET tag that I cannot find any documentation about through searching online and the previous developer is unavailable for questions.

Does anyone recognize this "blac" tag?  It's used in these two ways in the project I'm working with:

```
<blac:PriorityLabel>
<blac:DBDataSource>
```

I'm not sure why the tag is "blac:" and not "asp:".

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: User control definition?

Comment: Do a find for "blac" in the file and you'll see it referenced as an attribute on another tag (UserControl), its a way of "including" functionality from another file. See here for info about whats going on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you for the informative link bUKaneer.  I had to expand my search to the entire project but I did find the @Register TaxPrefix for "blac" in the project's web.config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a alias to a user control. For example:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="scott" TagName="header" Src="Controls/Header.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="scott" TagName="footer" Src="Controls/Footer.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ControlVendor" Assembly="ControlVendor" %>

<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <scott:header ID="MyHeader" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably post where you got this from: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config

Comment: Thank you for the example Thiago Custodio.  And thank you for the source link Green Chili.